# Batch downloading is not working

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am interested to calculate monthly ET from 8-day MODIS ET product. Code is running fine but for downloading the imageCollection, there's no task in the task window. Where am I wrong?

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3fde3368835243a1e14803c07b129086

```
var modET = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD16A2"),
    roi = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-arjzaidi/assets/FAO_GW/Analysis_Extent");

// Center the map on region of interest
Map.centerObject(roi,6);

// Add layer to the mapm
Map.addLayer(roi,{}, 'ROI')

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// EXERCISE 1: Obtain annual ET image and zonal statistics 
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

// set period
var startyear = 2022;
var startmonth = 1;
var startday = 1;

var endyear = 2022;
var endmonth = 12;
var endday = 30;

var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear,startmonth,startday);
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear,endmonth,endday);


var ET = modET
.select('ET')
.filterBounds(roi)
//clip image collection
 .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)});


var filteredET = ET.filterDate(startdate,enddate);

var evapotranspirationVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1000.0,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'fcd163', '99b718', '66a000', '3e8601', '207401', '056201',
    '004c00', '011301'
  ],
};



// -----------------------------------------------------------------
//            GENERATION OF ET LEGEND 
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Create a legend panel.
var legend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-right'
  }
});

// Create and add the legend title.
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'ET Legend',
  style: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '18px',
    margin: '0 0 4px 0',
    padding: '0'
  }
});
legend.add(legendTitle);

// Create and add the legend entries.
var makeRow = function(color, name) {
  // Create the label that displays the color and name.
  var colorBox = ui.Label({
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#' + color,
      padding: '8px',
      margin: '0 0 4px 0'
    }
  });
  var description = ui.Label({
    value: name,
    style: {
      margin: '0 0 4px 6px'
    }
  });
  // Return the panel that contains the label.
  return ui.Panel({
    widgets: [colorBox, description],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
  });
};

var palette = evapotranspirationVis.palette;
for (var i = 0; i < palette.length; i++) {
  var color = palette[i];
  var name = evapotranspirationVis.min + i * (evapotranspirationVis.max - evapotranspirationVis.min) / (palette.length - 1);
  legend.add(makeRow(color, name));
}

// Add the legend panel to the map.
Map.add(legend);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Check the number of images within the time range
var formatDate = function(date){
  var formattedDate = ee.Date(date).format('YYYY-MM-dd')
  return formattedDate
};
print('Number of images within the time range:', filteredET.size().getInfo());
print('List of dates within the time range:',
filteredET.aggregate_array('system:time_start').map(formatDate));



// -------------------------------------------------------
// EXERCISE 2: Calculate evapotranspiration for each month
// -------------------------------------------------------

// // Calculate ET for each month
var months = ee.List.sequence(startmonth,endmonth);
var years = ee.List.sequence(startyear,endyear);

var monthlyET =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
  return months.map(function(m){
  var w = filteredET.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
          .sum().multiply(0.1);
  return w.set('year', y)
          .set('month', m)
          .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1))
          .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1)) 
                        
});
}).flatten());

print(monthlyET,{},'MonthlyET');

var monthlyET1 = ee.ImageCollection(monthlyET);
print(monthlyET1,'MonthlyET1');

// setup the chart
var chartOptions = {
  title: 'Average Monthly Evapotranspiration',
  hAxis: {title: 'Time', format: 'MM-yy', gridlines: {count: 12}},
  vAxis: {title: 'Total ET (kg/m^2/month)'},
};

// Declare and print the chart
var monthlyETchart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: monthlyET, 
  region: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale:500,
})
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions(chartOptions);

// Plot the chart    
print('Average Monthly Evapotranspiration', monthlyETchart);


var ETJan22 = monthlyET.filterDate('2022-01-01').first();
Map.addLayer(ETJan22,evapotranspirationVis,'January 2022');
print (ETJan22, 'ETJan22');
//Export.image.toDrive(ETJan22);

//Export  ET ImageCollection 
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(monthlyET1, 
                'monthlyET', 
              {scale: 500, 
            //   maxPixels:1e13,   //If you do not specify maxPixels, the default value is used.
                region: roi,
              type:'float',
                //fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
                });
```